Windows 11: screen timeout settings don't apply when connected to a docking station
When connected to my docking station, my screen dims after 20 seconds and times out after 25 seconds regardless of what my power settings are. I have no problems when using the laptop directly.
I've tried all the troubleshooting steps related to screen timeouts (through the control panel, cmd etc..) but the issue persists.
I'm on an up-to-date Lenovo X1 Carbon running Windows 11 Pro with the latest updates (build 22631.4317). I'm connected to a Lenovo dock and an LG 29WQ600.
Am I missing something obvious? I can't seem to find screen-specific or dock specific settings to change.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
